# Error in source block since changing the names of my databases

Tags: anylogic

Since I changed the names of my databases I get the error **The method selectFrom(RelationalPathBase<?>) in the type Utilities is not applicable for the arguments (PointNode)**. Before I changed the names of them everything was okay. The error relies to the source blocks

```
(int) selectFrom(dbase1)
    .where(dbase1.arrivaltime(self.arrivalDate()))
    .firstResult(dbase1.n)
```

What is the problem? I also changed the dbase names in the functions. It marks me all selectfrom methods in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you did not use code-complete and just typed, correct?

Either re-do with code-complete (Ctrl+space) or re-apply the dbase wizard to re-write the statement for you.

PS: Although the error is actually hinting that you did change something beyond the dbase name, but try this first. Else, provide more info, screenshots...

Comment: I did. The problem was the names of my databases they were obviously to short.

Comment: Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)